# Does it make sense if I use " conflicted " in this sentence?

Tags: example

I'm wondering if it is okay to use " conflicted " in below sentence.
( I'd like to use " conflicted " instead of " concerned " or " worried ")

Example)
They are very **conflicted** about how they can reduce the amount of disposable products especially from restaurants and cafes in pandemic situation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the nature of the conflict?

Comment: _Conflicted_ implies the existence of two opposing viewpoints on the subject.

Comment: 1. The English style is “sentence below”. 2. I would avoid the use of conflicted completely. It is an ugly (IMHO)  neologism, that is unclear to me, and unnecessary because there are simpler ways of conveying the idea. If you are a non-native speaker you would benefit from using them. So what do you want to say? That they can’t decide what to do, that they don’t know what to do, they can’t agree what to do, or what? Notice that as a native speaker and academic, I was able to suggest phrases with words of one or two syllable. But then, my approach conflicts (valid usage) with yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kate Bunting said, there needs to be some sort of **conflict** between two options: if they are just generally worried or concerned about the use of disposable items, then we cannot use "conflicted."

However, if the option of replacing the disposable products with either recyclable or non-disposable products (e.g. metal cutlery rather than plastic) means higher costs and other negative consequences (more staff time to process non-disposable items), then there is a **conflict** between their desire to reduce the use of disposable items and the incurring of additional costs. In such a case they could accurately be described as "conflicted."

For example: "They are very conflicted about how they can reduce the amount of disposable products, especially from restaurants and cafes, in a pandemic situation **without at the same time driving up costs at a time when businesses are already under financial pressure**."

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Ruairi !

When we use " conflict " in a sentence, there should be two opposing opinion on one issue, is this correct?
I can see that my example was not clear to use " conflict ".